# Generate Search Issue when searching just few specific strings on Magento 2.3.2

Tags: magento2, php, catalogsearch

[image][image]

When I am searching on `Magento 2.3.2` website it is generating error as I have provided the image below. It generates results which looks like queries and generate on a specific string.

Please help me out.

Enter image description here

Comment: You need to look into your third party extension which you're using for search auto complete otherwise you need to check your custom code for it first.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is not error.

Some bots try to make sql injection over quick search field and it stored database like search term.

You can manage this search request in admin panel `Marketing > Search Terms`

Comment: how to avoid these sql injection , through admin panel Marketing > search it will delete only search suggestion ? any patches for sql injection for magento 2.3.2 ? please recommend to me.

Comment: There no injection. You see such text because someone tried to test if here any